# Update one MySQL table with values from another table based on id match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have these 2 tables below :

```
users:
         id 7dexpn
=========== ==========
          1 0
          2 0
          3 0


user_pages:
        id     user_id 7dexpf
========== =========== ==========
       99           1 0
       98           2 1
       97           3 1
       96           3 1
       95           3 1
       94           2 0
```

I am trying to insert { user_pages aggregate of (7dexpf) flags} into users table (7dexpn) matching by **user_pages (user_id)** with **users table (id)**

Expected results should be:

```
users:
         id 7dexpn
=========== ==========
          1 0
          2 1
          3 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to aggregate the values in `user_pages` and then assign them.  I would do:

```
update users u join
       (select user_id, count(*) as cnt
        from user_pages 
        where `7dexpf` = 1
        group by user_id
       ) uu
       on uu.user_id = u.id
    set u.`7dexpn` = uu.cnt;
```

Comment: it's works great just little problem, " if above statement is false i want to revert back flag to 0 i.e: [ set u.`7dexpn` = uu.cnt; ELSE set u.`7dexpn` = 0; ] it not working for me i hope you can solve this well

Comment: @GoargeGo . . . You should ask additional questions as a new question rather than as a comment.

Comment: alright,,,, here we go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993308/update-one-mysql-table-value-based-on-another-by-id-match-with-conditions

Answer (score 1):

Try using below query

```
 UPDATE users u,
 (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        SUM(7dexpf) AS 7dexpf
    FROM
        user_pages up
    GROUP BY
        user_id
) upp
SET 7dexpn = upp.7dexpf
WHERE
    u.id = upp.user_id
```

Comment: i am looking to update " users" table please edit, so i try

Comment: i am updating my answers. Please try now hope it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join this way for aggregated  value

```
update users u 
join (  select user_id, sum( case when `7dexpf` =1 1 else 0 end ) tot_7dexpf 
        from user_pages 
        group by user_id) t1 on t1.user_id = u.id
set u.`7dexpf` = t1tot_7dexpf
```

And i suggest io of avoid columns name starting with digit or in this case use backticks eg :

```
  `7dexpf`
```

Comment: what is tot_ 7dexpf &  1 else 0 end role here ? i think something should be looks like this update users u set 7dexpn
join (  select user_id, sum( case when `7dexpf` =1 ) tot_ 7dexpf 
        from user_pages 
        group by user_id) t1 on t1.user_id = u.id

Answer (score 0):

i did it successfully by doing like this way cheers to community

```
$query=" UPDATE users c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, SUM(7dexpf) as total
  FROM user_pages
  GROUP BY user_id
) x ON c.id = x.user_id
SET c.7dexpn = x.total
";
```