# update one MySQL table value based on another by id match with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have these 2 tables below :
users:

```
         id 7dexpn
=========== ==========
          1 0
          2 0
          3 0


user_pages:
        id     user_id 7dexpf
========== =========== ==========
       99           1 0
       98           2 1
       97           3 1
       96           3 1
       95           3 1
       94           2 0
```

I have successfully insert { user_pages aggregate of (7dexpf) flags} into users table (7dexpn) matching by user_pages (user_id) with users table (id)
with this query

```
update users u join
       (select user_id, count(*) as cnt
        from user_pages 
        where `7dexpf` = 1
        group by user_id
       ) uu
       on uu.user_id = u.id
    set u.`7dexpn` = uu.cnt;
```

But the query not update flag back to zero if u.`7dexpn` = 0

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.  Can you update your question to show what output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE()` :

```
UPDATE users u 
LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM user_pages 
      WHERE `7dexpf` = 1
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) uu
 ON uu.user_id = u.id
SET u.`7dexpn` = COALESCE(uu.cnt,0);
```